# HTML-Snippet to integrate account information into my website

Tags: support, user-accounts

I know that there's a possibility to generate a html snippet to integrate some account information into my website (name, points and badgets). But I cannot find the place in SO where I can get it... so where is it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it located under the "flair" tab on your account page. (Look in the middle right of that page under your info area) Hope this helps.
Cheers!